# Junit Mockito Exception while testing Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

Application: Spring MVC, JUnit, Mockito

Query: Unable to test Spring MVC application. Getting error related to "-servlet.xml" file not getting loaded successfully with ContextConfiguration.

Following is the source code:
The file that is to be tested exists in src/test/java
The -servlet-test.xml file exists in src/test/resource. This file contain all the required configuration (DAO, beans...)

recipe-servlet-test.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.recipe" />

<!-- Bean declarations -->
<bean id="recipeController" class="com.recipe.mvc.RecipeController" />

<!-- Menu list for Configuration menu -->
<util:list id="configMenuList" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>Cuisine</value>
    <value>Person</value>
    <!-- <value>Ingredients</value> -->
</util:list>

<!-- Handler for serving static resources -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources" mapping="/resources/**" />

<!-- Configure property files -->
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:spring/jdbc.properties, classpath:spring/business-config.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" local-override="false"
    ignore-unresolvable="false" properties-ref="defaultConfiguration" />

<util:properties id="defaultConfiguration">
    <!-- <prop key="hitransactionevent.hitransactioneventid">1</prop> -->
</util:properties>

<!--Configuration to connect to Oracle -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${home.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${home.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${home.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${home.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${home.jdbc.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${home.jdbc.maxActive}" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Session Factory Configuration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.recipe" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${home.jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction's Manager - using Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Enable annotation driven Transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Define transactions -->
<tx:advice transaction-manager="transactionManager" id="txAdvise">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" />
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvise"
        pointcut="execution(* com.recipe.service.RecipeServices.*(..))" />
</aop:config>
```

Test file..

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:recipe-servlet-test.xml"})
    public class ConfigCuisineControllerTest {
    @Mock
    private ConfigServices configServices;

    @InjectMocks
    private ConfigCuisineController configCuisineController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(configCuisineController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCuisine() throws Exception{
        List<Cuisine> cuisines = asList(new Cuisine(), new Cuisine(), new Cuisine());
        when(configServices.getCuisine()).thenReturn(cuisines);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/config/cuisine"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("config/cuisines"));
    }
}
```

Few relevant JARs are:

```
        <!-- Testing Jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Start Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

mvn dependency tree

```
    $ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Recipe Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ Recipe ---
[INFO] Recipe:Recipe:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:jar:1.0.0.M1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.11:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.984s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 31 17:19:11 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Exception is :

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilderSupport.createMockMvc(MockMvcBuilderSupport.java:50)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.build(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:207)
    at com.test.mvc.ConfigCuisineControllerTest.setup(ConfigCuisineControllerTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: do you have spring-web-*RELEASE jar in your class path?

Comment: Yup.. spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE is on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The interface `CallableProcessingInterceptor` is introduced in spring-web version 3.2 so you have to change your dependency version 3.2 or newer.

From interface [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor.html):

```
public interface CallableProcessingInterceptor 
Intercepts concurrent request handling, where the concurrent result is obtained by executing a Callable on behalf of the application with an AsyncTaskExecutor.
 A CallableProcessingInterceptor is invoked before and after the invocation of the Callable task in the asynchronous thread, as well as on timeout from a container thread, or after completing for any reason including a timeout or network error.

As a general rule exceptions raised by interceptor methods will cause async processing to resume by dispatching back to the container and using the Exception instance as the concurrent result. Such exceptions will then be processed through the HandlerExceptionResolver mechanism.

The afterTimeout method can select a value to be used to resume processing.
 Since: 3.2 Author: Rossen Stoyanchev
```